# Run python Webserver as Windows service

Tags: python, windows, unix, cgi

I have server and console [scripts](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/CGIHTTPServer.py) which keeps on listening on port for console and server requests.

In UNIX environment I made both the server and console script as continuously running daemons which will keep them listening on port.

Is there any way way in windows to keep them running like daemon in UNIX ? I also want them to get up on reboot (should get auto started on reboot)

I read about windows services and followed code written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how#answer-32440), but I am getting 404 error on my webpage

```
__version__ = "0.4"

__all__ = ["RequestHandler"]

import atexit
import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer
import copy
import os
import select
import SimpleHTTPServer
import sys
import time
import threading
import urllib

from signal import SIGTERM
from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

class RequestHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):


    have_fork = hasattr(os, 'fork')
    have_popen2 = hasattr(os, 'popen2')
    have_popen3 = hasattr(os, 'popen3')


    rbufsize = 0

    def do_POST(self):

        if self.is_cgi():
            self.run_cgi()
        else:
            self.send_error(501, "Can only POST to CGI scripts")

    def send_head(self):

        if self.is_cgi():
            return self.run_cgi()
        else:
            return SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.send_head(self)

    def is_cgi(self):

        splitpath = _url_collapse_path_split(self.path)
        if splitpath[0] in self.cgi_directories:
            self.cgi_info = splitpath
            return True
        return False

    cgi_directories = ['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']

    def is_executable(self, path):

        return executable(path)

    def is_python(self, path):

        head, tail = os.path.splitext(path)
        return tail.lower() in (".py", ".pyw")

    def run_cgi(self):

        path = self.path
        dir, rest = self.cgi_info

        i = path.find('/', len(dir) + 1)
        while i >= 0:
            nextdir = path[:i]
            nextrest = path[i+1:]

            scriptdir = self.translate_path(nextdir)
            if os.path.isdir(scriptdir):
                dir, rest = nextdir, nextrest
                i = path.find('/', len(dir) + 1)
            else:
                break


        i = rest.rfind('?')
        if i >= 0:
            rest, query = rest[:i], rest[i+1:]
        else:
            query = ''

        i = rest.find('/')
        if i >= 0:
            script, rest = rest[:i], rest[i:]
        else:
            script, rest = rest, ''

        scriptname = dir + '/' + script
        scriptfile = self.translate_path(scriptname)
        if not os.path.exists(scriptfile):
            self.send_error(404, "No such CGI script (%r)" % scriptname)
            return
        if not os.path.isfile(scriptfile):
            self.send_error(403, "CGI script is not a plain file (%r)" %
                            scriptname)
            return
        ispy = self.is_python(scriptname)
        if not ispy:
            if not (self.have_fork or self.have_popen2 or self.have_popen3):
                self.send_error(403, "CGI script is not a Python script (%r)" %
                                scriptname)
                return
            if not self.is_executable(scriptfile):
                self.send_error(403, "CGI script is not executable (%r)" %
                                scriptname)
                return

        # Reference: http://hoohoo.ncsa.uiuc.edu/cgi/env.html
        # XXX Much of the following could be prepared ahead of time!
        env = {}
        env['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] = self.version_string()
        env['SERVER_NAME'] = self.server.server_name
        env['GATEWAY_INTERFACE'] = 'CGI/1.1'
        env['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = self.protocol_version
        env['SERVER_PORT'] = str(self.server.server_port)
        env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = self.command
        uqrest = urllib.unquote(rest)
        env['PATH_INFO'] = uqrest
        env['PATH_TRANSLATED'] = self.translate_path(uqrest)
        env['SCRIPT_NAME'] = scriptname
        if query:
            env['QUERY_STRING'] = query
        host = self.address_string()
        if host != self.client_address[0]:
            env['REMOTE_HOST'] = host
        env['REMOTE_ADDR'] = self.client_address[0]
        authorization = self.headers.getheader("authorization")
        if authorization:
            authorization = authorization.split()
            if len(authorization) == 2:
                import base64, binascii
                env['AUTH_TYPE'] = authorization[0]
                if authorization[0].lower() == "basic":
                    try:
                        authorization = base64.decodestring(authorization[1])
                    except binascii.Error:
                        pass
                    else:
                        authorization = authorization.split(':')
                        if len(authorization) == 2:
                            env['REMOTE_USER'] = authorization[0]
        # XXX REMOTE_IDENT
        if self.headers.typeheader is None:
            env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = self.headers.type
        else:
            env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = self.headers.typeheader
        length = self.headers.getheader('content-length')
        if length:
            env['CONTENT_LENGTH'] = length
        referer = self.headers.getheader('referer')
        if referer:
            env['HTTP_REFERER'] = referer
        accept = []
        for line in self.headers.getallmatchingheaders('accept'):
            if line[:1] in "\t\n\r ":
                accept.append(line.strip())
            else:
                accept = accept + line[7:].split(',')
        env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = ','.join(accept)
        ua = self.headers.getheader('user-agent')
        if ua:
            env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = ua
        co = filter(None, self.headers.getheaders('cookie'))
        if co:
            env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = ', '.join(co)
        # XXX Other HTTP_* headers
        # Since we're setting the env in the parent, provide empty
        # values to override previously set values
        for k in ('QUERY_STRING', 'REMOTE_HOST', 'CONTENT_LENGTH',
                  'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'HTTP_COOKIE', 'HTTP_REFERER'):
            env.setdefault(k, "")
        os.environ.update(env)

        self.send_response(200, "Script output follows")

        decoded_query = query.replace('+', ' ')

        if self.have_fork:
            # Unix -- fork as we should
            args = [script]
            if '=' not in decoded_query:
                args.append(decoded_query)
            nobody = nobody_uid()
            self.wfile.flush() # Always flush before forking
            pid = os.fork()
            if pid != 0:
                # Parent
                pid, sts = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
                # throw away additional data [see bug #427345]
                while select.select([self.rfile], [], [], 0)[0]:
                    if not self.rfile.read(1):
                        break
                if sts:
                    self.log_error("CGI script exit status %#x", sts)
                return
            # Child
            try:
                try:
                    os.setuid(nobody)
                except os.error:
                    pass
                os.dup2(self.rfile.fileno(), 0)
                os.dup2(self.wfile.fileno(), 1)
                os.execve(scriptfile, args, os.environ)
            except:
                self.server.handle_error(self.request, self.client_address)
                os._exit(127)

        else:
            # Non Unix - use subprocess
            import subprocess
            cmdline = [scriptfile]
            if self.is_python(scriptfile):
                interp = sys.executable
                if interp.lower().endswith("w.exe"):
                    # On Windows, use python.exe, not pythonw.exe
                    interp = interp[:-5] + interp[-4:]
                cmdline = [interp, '-u'] + cmdline
            if '=' not in query:
                cmdline.append(query)

            self.log_message("command: %s", subprocess.list2cmdline(cmdline))
            try:
                nbytes = int(length)
            except (TypeError, ValueError):
                nbytes = 0
            p = subprocess.Popen(cmdline,
                                 stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                                 stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                                )
            if self.command.lower() == "post" and nbytes > 0:
                data = self.rfile.read(nbytes)
            else:
                data = None
            # throw away additional data [see bug #427345]
            while select.select([self.rfile._sock], [], [], 0)[0]:
                if not self.rfile._sock.recv(1):
                    break
            stdout, stderr = p.communicate(data)
            self.wfile.write(stdout)
            if stderr:
                self.log_error('%s', stderr)
            status = p.returncode
            if status:
                self.log_error("CGI script exit status %#x", status)
            else:
                self.log_message("CGI script exited OK")



def _url_collapse_path_split(path):

    path_parts = []
    for part in path.split('/'):
        if part == '.':
            path_parts.append('')
        else:
            path_parts.append(part)
    # Filter out blank non trailing parts before consuming the '..'.
    path_parts = [part for part in path_parts[:-1] if part] + path_parts[-1:]
    if path_parts:
        tail_part = path_parts.pop()
    else:
        tail_part = ''
    head_parts = []
    for part in path_parts:
        if part == '..':
            head_parts.pop()
        else:
            head_parts.append(part)
    if tail_part and tail_part == '..':
        head_parts.pop()
        tail_part = ''
    return ('/' + '/'.join(head_parts), tail_part)


nobody = None

def nobody_uid():
    """Internal routine to get nobody's uid"""
    global nobody
    if nobody:
        return nobody
    try:
        import pwd
    except ImportError:
        return -1
    try:
        nobody = pwd.getpwnam('nobody')[2]
    except KeyError:
        nobody = 1 + max(map(lambda x: x[2], pwd.getpwall()))
    return nobody


def executable(path):
    """Test for executable file."""
    try:
        st = os.stat(path)
    except os.error:
        return False
    return st.st_mode & 0111 != 0

Handler = RequestHandler

PORT = 7998
ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0"

httpd = ThreadedHTTPServer((ADDRESS, PORT), Handler)
print "serving at %s:%s" % (ADDRESS, PORT)

import os
import SocketServer
import BaseHTTPServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import xmlrpclib
import SimpleXMLRPCServer 
import socket
import httplib
import inspect
import win32service
import win32serviceutil
import win32api
import win32con
import win32event
import win32evtlogutil

class XMLRPCServerService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_         = "XMLRPCServerService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "XMLRPCServerService"
    _svc_description_  = "Tests Python service framework by receiving and echoing messages over a named pipe"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)                    

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        import servicemanager
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,(self._svc_name_, '')) 
        self.timeout = 100

        while 1:            
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("XMLRPCServerService - STOPPED")
                break
            else:
                httpd.serve_forever()
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("XMLRPCServerService - is alive and well")

def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)   
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(XMLRPCServerService)
```

Any clues where I am going wrong ? Or good way to implement it (May be w/o using service).

### Strict Note:

Solution must be in Python 2.6 (Project requirements).

---

### Updates:

I saw some weird thing in log:`python service.py debug`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2014 09:41:04] command: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win3
2\**pythonservice.exe** -u C:\CONSOLE-CGI\cgi-bin\login.py ""
```

Why is executing CGI script using `pythonservice.exe`?

What am I missing Here?

### More updates:

Code snippet from daemon process python script

```
#Non Unix - use subprocess
import subprocess
cmdline = [scriptfile]
if self.is_python(scriptfile): 
    #interp = sys.executable // here it return pythonservice.exe
    interp = "python.exe" // if I hardcode it to python.exe all goes fine        
    if interp.lower().endswith("w.exe"): #On Windows,use python.exe,not pythonw.exe
    interp = interp[: -5] + interp[-4: ]
cmdline = [interp, '-u'] + cmdline
```

Any clues why is so??

Comment: Is it okay for you to configure this by hand? Or do you need a script to create the schedule because you want the server to run on 100 computers and configuring by hand is too much work. I bear it ;) It's ok. If you only need this on your computer you can do it with the mouse.

Comment: Somewhere you need code to tell windows that a special file must be executed by the task scheduler. Try searching for this. It shuld be possible  to do this in Python but I have no idea, how to do this. Good luck! If you have found something then you can add a link to it here.

Comment: I think I have to reopen bounty :-(

Answer (score 1):

You may need to redirect all the output since Windows scheduler has some issues doing this in pythonw case. Process does start properly, but no action being done and server does not respond without redirecting *stdout* and *stderr*.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import sys
 
PORT = 1234

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout = open('out.txt', 'w')
    sys.stderr = open('err.txt', 'w')
    with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
        print("serving at port %d" % PORT, flush=True)
        httpd.serve_forever()
```