# Registering a Python program as a Windows Server 2003 R2 Service

Tags: python, windows-services, windows-server-2003

I wrote a Python script that I need to have installed on Windows Server 2003 R2, that will run when a specific directory is changed in any way (new files, deleted files, etc). I believe I need to register this as a system service, in order to listen for that, but I'm really not sure.

So, my question is this: does such a script need to be registered as a service, and if so, how do I go about doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your program will have to watch the directory for changes and act according.  Alternatively, you could have a separate program watch the directory and then invoke your script, but this is essentially the same.

Tim Golden has an article [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html) which discusses directory watching using python and the win32 api.

After you get that working, it would be very appropriate to have your program run as a service.  This has been covered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how).