# How can I keep Task Manager from killing my pythonw script?

Tags: python, windows, process, taskmanager

I want to run a python script for several days, performing a huge database calculation, on a "public" windows computer in my work place. 
Since this task is important, I want to prevent closing it from the task manager. 
Is it possible to protect a python script from being closed by the task manager (windows xp)? If it is, how?

Comment: May I suggest a manual/non-digital solution? Sticky Notes.

Comment: You should run it as service. -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you aren't giving "public" general users administrative privileges. Don't give the public account permission to close your script. Then you just run your script from a different user account than the account the general public can use.