# Start python .py as a service in windows

Tags: python, windows-services

I've created a windows service to start a .py script.

```
sc create "Maraschino" binPath= "C:\HTPC\Maraschino\maraschino-cherrypy.py" DisplayName=    "Maraschino" depend= "Tcpip"
```

Then I've added a registry key to link the .py to open using python.exe

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Maraschino\Parameters]
"AppDirectory"="C:\\Python27"
"Application"="C:\\Python27\\python.exe C:\\HTPC\\Maraschino\\maraschino-cherrypy.py"
```

However when I try start the service I get Error 193 0xc1 which when googled revealed that it isn't a valid exe I'm trying to start. I know its not an .exe but a .py and linking it to open with python.exe should fix this but I'm making an error. Does anyone have any insight into what I might be doing wrong when linking the script to use python.exe

Thanks

Comment: try calling the .pyc file instead.

Comment: @Marcom Thanks, but that doesn't work. Its an app so its all been compiled and to run it maraschino-cherrypy.py works when double clicked just not via services

Comment: All of these are duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+windows+service

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I run a Python script as a service (in Windows)? How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this using the **srvany.exe**, which is a tool from Microsoft dedicated for this kind of tasks.

First, download and install the [Windows Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=17657).
Note: You only need srvany.exe, which works on all versions of Windows.

Presuming that the Windows Resource Kit was installed at C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\ run:

```
sc create "[YourService]" binPath= "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\srvany.exe"
```

Now, run **regedit**.

In the Registry Editor dialog select
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SYSTEM > CurrentControlSet > Services > [YourService]`

With [YourService] selected, hit Edit > New > Key from the toolbar.

Type **Parameters** and hit enter.

From the toolbar select Edit > New > String Value.

Type **Application** and hit enter.

Right-click Application and select Modify.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\[YourServicePath].py
```

Hit the OK button.

And boom! you have a nice new service.

Comment: Okay thanks, I was hoping to get away without installing anything but this will work. Thanks

Comment: You don't actually have to install anything! Just get the srvany.exe (install it once and grab it, or google it).
Throw it in your script folder and set the binPath to it.
This is what we do in production environment.

Comment: srvany.exe - for new PC who do not have Windows resource kit how to install there?

Comment: YumYumYum you can download the windows resource kit, install it, then copy the srvany.exe to any folder you would like.  I copied it to the same folder containing the scripts that were used for the service.  Worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how sc works, but i think that must be some way to pass parameters to the binary, so you could try to register "C:\Python27\python.exe C:\HTPC\Maraschino\maraschino-cherrypy.py" instead.

You could also try [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Updates of @Ohad. First of all srvany.exe is to be deployed to all machines

Step 1:

- Download and install Windows Resource Kit.
- Which was found in my box: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe .
- Then open command prompt and hit

  sc create "[YourService]" binPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\srvany.exe" start=auto DisplayName="[YourService Monitor]"

  [SC] CreateService SUCCESS

Step 2: make a file.reg with following contents and double click on it

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[YourService]\Parameters]
"Application"="C:\\[YourService Executable].exe"
```

Step 3: now start service and it will execute what-ever you have assigned in the file.reg

Done