# How can I execute my program cleanly without the command prompt open in background?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, exe, command-prompt

I'm pretty new to coding so bear with me.  I coded a simple program in python 3 and created an .exe file with pyinstaller.  I noticed that when i open the .exe, the cmd window opens as well and runs in the background. How would I go about running it silently, so just my window opens up. thanks for any insight

Comment: Having a look through [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799155/python-how-can-i-hide-the-windows-command-prompt-screen-when-the-script-is-run) should help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - how can i hide the windows command prompt screen when the script is running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799155/python-how-can-i-hide-the-windows-command-prompt-screen-when-the-script-is-run)

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but I was looking for this myself now and I found a solution.
When generating the .exe with pyinstaller, you can pass the option `--hide-console {minimize-late,hide-late,hide-early,minimize-early}`.

For example:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hide-console hide-early main.py
```

Source: https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-hide-console