# After converting python3 source code into an exe using auto-py-to-exe tool, console starts blinking while executing the exe

Tags: python, auto-py-to-exe

I am trying to play a video file using vlc media player through the subprocess command.While running the python3 source code in pycharm, video is played without any console blink. If I convert it to exe and run the application, I am able to see the console blinking, before the video is started to play. Video is played only after a while
(video is played only after console blinks, delay is seen).

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. A command window will open to launch any console executable, yes. The Pycharm terminal may open _minimized_, but it still is "open" while the script runs.

Comment: How to avoid this? any help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799155/python-how-can-i-hide-the-windows-command-prompt-screen-when-the-script-is-run

Comment: Or if it is using `pyinstaller`, did you look at the example docs that show `--noconsole` option?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @OneCricketeer, but the issue is different, it is not a fixed command prompt. The real issue is, I'm trying to open a video file using VLC media player through subprocess, at that time I can see command prompt starts blinking before opening the video file. (Video file is struggling to get open.)

Comment: Sounds like separate issues. You should be able to make pyinstaller "hide" the console on exe execution. Then if `subprocess` isn't working, there should be an exception that you are not handing or logging (please show your code). Or VLC is simply slow, in which case, that isn't a Python problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If I create an exe with console enabled in auto-py-to-exe, console blink issue is not occurred.

Comment: But I want this issue to be solved even if the console is disabled.