# Recommendations for Python cross-platform listener server

Tags: python, cross-platform, listener

I need to create a simple server/daemon which just waits for commands, (maybe queues them up), and executes other commands based on the received input. Here are more detailed requirements:

- Should be in Python since I need to use some other Python code I wrote for it.
- Needs to work on at least Linux and Windows (Will be running as an init.d service on Linux and
  as a Windows Service on Windows)
- Communication medium should be as simple as possible and hopefully commands can be sent to the server from a batch script
- Commands come from the same machine. Performance isn't important.
- Installation on Windows (including all the libraries needed to send a command to the server from a script) should be simple. If everything can be wrapped into a single `.exe` all the better.

What's the best stack to use for this? I have only a few vague ideas:

- CherryPy (Windows doesn't have cURL though, ugh...)
- dbus and windbus (never used these before...)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience (and I've implemented three or four applications similar to what you've described), all things created equal, and I've found it simplest to go with a subclass of [SocketServer.TCPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#socketserver-tcpserver-example) and implement my own, simple, command system. This gives you full control over the details (need streaming? No problem; need stateful connections? No problem), and isn't all that tricky given some basic knowledge of how sockets work.

On Windows, I understand that [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) does a good job.

A couple alternatives/tools you might want to consider:

- [SimpleXMLRPCServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#module-SimpleXMLRPCServer) and [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) — if you can live with the constraints imposed by HTTP + XMLRPC (stateless, streaming is tricky) this will get you up and running in about 5 minutes. Also note that the SimpleXMLRPCServer is single-threaded. It's possible to make it multi-threaded (or multi-process, or whatever), but that will take a little bit of work.
- On Linux, [python-daemon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) is a possibility for daemonizing, but I've usually found `start-stop-daemon` to be simpler (if it's available on your platform)
- [Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how) should help you running the script as a service.