# Building an EXE with a Flask server included

Tags: python, flask

I'm attempting to build an application that runs locally on a user's computer. It takes inputs and displays information, so I thought a nice way to make it work would be to have a Flask server that handles web forms, etc, to gather user input, and to display database contents in tables.

The service works when I run the Flask development server, and everything is fine and dandy, but I want to compile the entire project into a single executable file.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible for me to have the flask server automatically start up and open the portal page when I double-click the EXE
2. Assuming this is a feasible concept, how would I go about compiling the exe? A brief look through the [pyinstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html) does not tell me how I would compile a folder (which in this case would be more of a Python package), which would be a necessary pre-requisite considering that Flask has `static` and `template` folders containing my HTML, CSS, and JS files, not to mention the fact that my file tree is built in a modular manner.
3. Am I approaching this the wrong way? Would it be better to build a "launcher" application that runs Flask as a Windows service (vis a vis [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55677165/python-flask-as-windows-service)) instead of attempting to have an all-in-one EXE?

For reference, my file tree looks something like this:

```
Application
|_static
|_templates
|_\templates\errors
|_\templates\forms
|_errors
|_database
|_\database\connections
|_\database\iohandlers
|_"__init__.py"
|_"app.py"
```

While doing research on this, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202711/is-there-an-easy-way-to-distribute-a-flask-server-as-an-executable) but as my situation doesn't mesh with the model that the OP had laid out, I thought it would be pertinent and useful to ask another question.

Comment: this may [help](https://elc.github.io/posts/executable-flask-pyinstaller/) why not host the flask server in cloud ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 I'm not hosting the flask server in the cloud because the project it is for is not worth the hosting space & cost. (minimal as it may be)

Comment: there are free services provided by heroku, you can use those, if no of call to website is not that much. i added a link , maybe that can help yu

Comment: Ahh I got the question wrong, He wants to run it locally on a computer.

Comment: @AbrarAhmed Well, yes...
`I'm attempting to build an application that runs locally on a user's computer.` Thank you for the site though, I'm going to investigate it, it's just not incredibly useful for my particular issue.

Comment: @FinneganMcCarthy Beyond my scope of knowledge :)