# How to play a video from a Windows service in Python

Tags: python, windows, windows-services

I use the technique described in this post:

[Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how)

to make a Windows service in Python. I starts OSC and waits for a message to start a video. The thing is, I can't make it start a video. At any stage. I used `subprocess.call`, I used `os.startfile` and I used `win32api.WinExec`. I put the command in a `.bat` file and started that. Nothing worked. Is it impossible?

I changed the script to start the video when the service starts, so this is not an OSC problem.

Comment: By default, a Windows Service has no access to desktop functions, which are needed to play videos.

Comment: @AdamVandenberg You said "by default". Is it possible to change that?

Comment: "Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. " http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't know how to use that. I'll just make a program with an infinite loop.