# Python run a method in background

Tags: python, scripting, python-2.4

I have written a simple http server by extending `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`. I am able to start it and process requests successfully. However it runs in the foreground, and the only way I can think of making it run in the background is to wrap it with a shell script and use `nohup`, `&` etc
Is there any way I can do this within the python script itself?

Comment: You'll want to look into the multiprocessing module.

Comment: @johnthexiii as far as I understand multithreading will still keep the program in foreground, this is true in many languages, ex: in java I can start a thread but my main program stays in the foreground still, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Check out the python daemon module.

Comment: Sorry misread you question, anyways if you're on a *nix system you'll want to look into daemons, if you're on windows look into [services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how).