# Python 3 executable as windows service

Tags: python, windows, service, cx-freeze

I'm trying to write a windows Service in python, but the tricky part is i want to deploy it on a machine that doesn't have python.
I've successfully created a service like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/can-i-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-how), and it works if i run from my machine. the problem starts when i try to convert it to an exe and then try to install it.
first i tried to use cx_freeze service example, (seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/4fa5dfdaae24/samples/service/?at=default)), the setup.py look like this :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

options = {'build_exe': {'includes': ['ServiceHandler']}}

executables = [Executable('Config.py', base='Win32Service', targetName='gsr.exe')]

setup(name='GSR',
    version='0.1',
    description='GSR SERVICE',
    executables=executables,
    options=options
    )
```

and config.py is:

```
NAME = 'GSR_%s'
DISPLAY_NAME = 'GSR TEST - %s'
MODULE_NAME = 'ServiceHandler'
CLASS_NAME = 'Handler'
DESCRIPTION = 'Sample service description'
AUTO_START = True
SESSION_CHANGES = False
```

but when i try to build it (python setup.py build) i get an error:
"cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Win32Service"

Second, i tried using a regular cx_freeze setup, the exe i get installs the service fine but once i try to start it i get an error:
"Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

setup.py - python 3.3 regualr exe, installs the service but when trying to start it sends an error:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

packages = ['win32serviceutil','win32service','win32event','servicemanager','socket','win32timezone','cx_Logging','ServiceHandler']
build_exe_options = {"packages": packages}
executable = [Executable("ServiceHandler.py")]


setup(  name = "GSR_test",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "GSR test service",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = executable)
```

finally, I managed to get it to work in python 2.7 using py2exe, but py2exe isn't available for python 3.3 and I my code is in 3.3

i guess the problem is in the configuration of the setup.py im using with cx_freeze. 
any ideas ??

my ServiceHandler:

```
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket
from test import test
import threading

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "GSR_test"
    _svc_display_name_ = "GSR test Service"

    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.app = test()
        self.flag = threading.Event()

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.flag.set()

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.app.run)
        t.start()
        self.flag.wait()
        raise SystemExit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Setup.py , python 2.7 using py2exe that works: (taken from [here](https://www.evanreichard.com/?p=86))

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(  service = ["ServiceHandler"],
        description = "SERVICE TEST",
        modules = ["GSR_test"],
        cmdline_style='pywin32', )
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: What doesn't work? Are there any errors logged?

Comment: I updated the question and included more details

Comment: The Win32service base only supports Python 2 at the moment. It's waiting for someone to add Python 3 support.

Comment: No. it's as Thomas K said, the wind32service base in not compatible with python 3 last time I checked. The file is available in c but adjustments need to be made from python 2 to 3 AFAK. I ended up still using python 2.7. If you find a solution, please share :)

Answer (score 13):

**tldr** Python 3.5 Windows Service build with pyinstaller : [gist](https://gist.github.com/guillaumevincent/d8d94a0a44a7ec13def7f96bfb713d3f)

Here a simple Windows Service with python :

`WindowsService.py`

```
import servicemanager
import socket
import sys
import win32event
import win32service
import win32serviceutil


class TestService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "TestService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        rc = None
        while rc != win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            with open('C:\\TestService.log', 'a') as f:
                f.write('test service running...\n')
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, 5000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(TestService)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(TestService)
```

Create an exe with pyinstaller (`pip install pyinstaller`) and python 3.5 :

```
(env)$ python -V
Python 3.5.2

(env)$ pip freeze
PyInstaller==3.2

(env)$ pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=win32timezone WindowsService.py
```

Install and run the service

```
(env) dist\WindowsService.exe install
Installing service TestService
Service installed

(env) dist\WindowsService.exe start
Starting service TestService
```

Check `C:\\TestService.log` file.

Stop and clean

```
(env) dist\WindowsService.exe stop
(env) dist\WindowsService.exe remove
```

Comment: It really works! Thank you!  (Python 3.6.3, PyInstaller==3.3)

Comment: How is `TestService` linked to the main application script?

Answer (score 1):

It appears Win32Service [was updated with Python 3.x support](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/pull-requests/49/make-win32service-work-with-python-3x/diff) within the cx_Freeze project as a result of [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/cx-freeze/mailman/message/30683093/). This user originally had the same issue you reported, so I'm assuming this will also resolve your issue.

Based on the error reported, it's caused when [_GetBaseFileName()](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/1282b6b6ee637738210113dd88c3c198d475340f/cx_Freeze/freezer.py?at=default#freezer.py-615) within Freezer.py fails to find the compiled Win32Service.exe. This executable should be built when cx_Freeze gets [built/installed](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/src/1282b6b6ee637738210113dd88c3c198d475340f/setup.py?at=default#setup.py-167).

If it's not too much to ask, can search the installed cx_Freeze installation directory for "Win32Service.exe" and confirm that it exists. Hopefully this gets you one step closer.

Comment: While the base file seems to be updated if i try to freeze a service (using the provided example from cx_freeze) i'm still getting an error -
cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Win32Service. and indeed if I go and look at the bases folder (with the exe not the c file) it's still missing (no win32Service.exe).. maybe it just need to be compiled and someone fortgot. Using cx_freeze v4.3.4

Comment: FYI a regular pip install of cx_Freeze won't have the cx_Logging folder in the folder above it, so the Win32Service base will not be compiled. If you download the source to both (to /tmp/cx_Freeze/ and /tmp/cx_Logging) then run `python setup.py install` on cx_Logging THEN cx_Freeze, you'll end up with the Win32Service base.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the `Win32Service.c` in the `cx_freeze` src for `python3` support

Edited it with some preprocessor commands, for python2 support too (but not tested for python2 yet)

1. download sources of `cx_freeze` from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=cx_Freeze&version=4.3.4) and extract it
2. download [cx_logging](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/cx-logging/cx_Logging-2.1.tar.gz?download) and extract it to the `cx_freeze-4.3.4` directory
3. replace the `Win32Service.c` file in `cx_Freeze-4.3.4\source\bases` with [my edited version](https://gist.github.com/microo8/6485a3f0ea42a1ed43337cd10cadbb18)
4. edit line 170 in `setup.py` from `if moduleInfo is not None and sys.version_info[:2] < (3, 0):` to `if moduleInfo is not None:`
5. run `python setup.py build` in `cx_freeze-4.3.4` directory (you must have MSC installed to compile the C source files)
6. copy `cx_Freeze-4.3.4\build\lib.win32-3.4\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32Service.exe` to `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\bases` (or the path where your python3 is installed)
7. now you can create frozen exe with the `Win32Service` base (no more the `cx_Freeze.freezer.ConfigError: no base named Win32Service` error)