# Task scheduler: Works only when I right-click on the task and start it manually

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, scheduled-tasks, taskscheduler

I've a python flask server file run.py which I want to start as soon as VM reboots. I've tried using the task scheduler on Windows (by basically creating a powershell file which calls run.py and feeding this powershell file to task scheduler) but it never runs on its own. But the strangest thing is, when I right-click on the task and manually start it - then it runs as expected. But when task scheduler does it - it fails.

What can I do to fix this? Any alternatives to task scheduler for running that python server on startup?

Comment: The task trigger condition might be not set up correctly. Anyway, configuring the Task Scheduler is more suitable to Super User or Server Fault.

Comment: Why not [configure it as a Windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550067/deploy-flask-app-as-windows-service) instead?