# Flask server process name

Tags: python

I have a flask application, which I need to restart sometimes. Currently I have to manually stop the flask server and restart it. Is there a way wherein I could assign name to flask server process, so that I could kill that process and then fire the `python app.py` command.

I need a way to kill only the flask server process.
Currently the flask server process is shown as `python` process in windows task manager.
I need a method to kill only one process and not other python processes.

I need a solution for windows system.

Comment: Maybe this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/2255466/9515831

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention I am working on windows

Comment: you could use this to get the pid of the process: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452056/435815, use this to kill the process: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17858114/13710015, and then you could use `subprocess.popen(shlex.split("python file.py"))`. You could then use something like pynput (https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106497/13710015) to stop the flask app and re-run it

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25130524/15239951