# Running Python service windows

Tags: python, service, cx-freeze

I need a program that on first run sets up an `update-checker`, that's my code-script, and makes it run as a service (no tray icon or etc.) on startup of the computer. I have the update script working...

Without PyPi packages, or suggest a way to install pyPi packages...

(I need to have it working when "compiled" to exe via `cx_freeze`.)

Running Python3 everywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32404/2382792

Comment: not duplicate. I'm using cx_freeze and I can't install pypi packages!

Comment: cx_Freeze has a `win32service` base for making services, but I don't know how you use it. For auto-updating, you might want to look at [esky](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/esky).