# How to continue running a python program in the background

Tags: windows-7, python-3.3, background-service

I'm writing a Python 3 program in Windows and I would like to be able to continue running the program in the background (not in the taskbar) to gather information.

I was able to create it as a service, but I need admin privileges to run and it stops immediately!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like what you want is to make your program a [Windows service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service). There's a bunch of good information in this other question: [Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32404/3958453)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried the code in the link in my program and I got printed instructions that I Don't understand: I put the instructions I got in my question. You can probably tell that I don't really know what i'm doing!

Comment: Also. Keep in mind that i'm going to eventually compile my code into an executable.

Comment: @Luke: I'm guessing your script is LIP.py, correct? and you ran it from the command line like: python LIP.py? If so, the usage output is telling you that you need to pass in some options to start your script as a service, try: python LIP.py --install

Comment: Yes. But I actually run it from IDLE, and after that, it should be an executable.

Comment: @LukeDinkler I'm fairly certain that the command line arg's will be the same when you run it as an exe, so you'll just start it: LIP --install.

Comment: Ok. I've run it from the command line, and it runs, but I don't see it under 'services' in the task manager, and how do I see if it is running in the backround?

Comment: Wait. Now it shows in the command line "option --install  not recognized"!

Comment: @LukeDinkler try adding --startup="auto" startup defaults to manual, but I'm not enough of a Windows guru to tell you how to manually start a service

Comment: Now it starts in the command line, but I get an error in the log, "Error installing service: Access is denied. (5)"!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60185/discussion-between-greg-chapman-and-luke-dinkler).