# How to create an executable that is a service or a normal process?

Tags: python, windows-services

I created a service based on this code [Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how)
But when i run the code I can only run it as a service and not a normal process.
Is it possible to create a script that when it is run by an admin it runs as a service, but when its activated without admin privileges it runs as a normal process?

Answer (score 1):

With `win32service` (some docs [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/win32service.html)) you can also get the user info by calling the method `GetUserObjectInformation`, with differente `type` parameters to get one of `UOI_FLAGS,UOI_NAME, UOI_TYPE, or UOI_USER_SID`. The complete list of user info types can be found [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/PyUSER_INFO_.2a.html).

To have a look just print the info somewhere on your program, like the snippet below. If the user name is all that you need `win32api` will get you there easier.

```
print win32api.GetUserName()
print win32service.GetUserObjectInformation( win32service.OpenInputDesktop(0,0,1), 4)
# or simply:
print win32service.GetUserObjectInformation( win32service.GetProcessWindowStation(), 4)
```

Finally, in order  to get the privileges directly you can use `win32net` like so:

```
    win32net.NetUserGetInfo(None, win32api.GetUserName() , 11 )['priv']
```

This will return an int which maps to:

- win32netcon.USER_PRIV_GUEST (0)
- win32netcon.USER_PRIV_USER (1)
- win32netcon.USER_PRIV_ADMIN (2)

In your program you can check if `win32net.NetUserGetInfo(None, win32api.GetUserName() , 11 )['priv'] == win32netcon.USER_PRIV_ADMIN` to launch it as a service or not.

For more information on the extensions you can find a brief reference [here](http://www.icodeguru.com/WebServer/Python-Programming-on-Win32/appb.htm).

Comment: I found some `not yet implemented` functionality. Hope this info is enough

Comment: why would I need a users name?

Comment: Doesn't work. When i run the service without admin it runs it as a normal process successfully. But when i start it as a service i get an error "The Windows ____ service on local computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs"

Comment: Well, it looks like the solution works for the part you asked (you can differentiate the type of user and launch not as a service if the user is not admin). I do understand that you could launch it as a service before, but that error does not explain anything at all. As much as I can see it is not a problem of differentiating the user. Can you build a minimal working example or at least post the code you wrote?

Comment: win32net.NetUserGetInfo(None, win32api.GetUserName() , 11 )['priv'] always return 2L, admin or not

Comment: You must be doing something wrong regarding your users, I just created a standar user on my pc and verified that `priv` is indeed 1L