# make python script run like a service or agent in Windows

Tags: python

I have written a python script that collect some WMI data from machine.

I want this script to run 24*7 and get the WMI data.

How can I get this script to execute 24/7, such as turning it into agent or service in Windows. 
I also need a loop that never ends in the program, or can it be done by just having the code re executed multiple times?

Thanks

Here the basic script.

```
import os
import time
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
def systeminfo1():
    for cpu in c.Win32_Processor():
        print('cpu_useper', cpu.LoadPercentage)
        
def systeminfo():
    for mem in c.Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory():
        print('Memused_perc', mem.PercentCommittedBytesInUse)
       
while True:
    systeminfo()
    time.sleep(5)
    systeminfo1()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: I suggest you investigate [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/), this can be used to package your script as a Windows service.

Comment: Why can you not have a bat file that runs based on the scheduler in windows? Wouldn't that be super simple?

Comment: If i need to run this script on more than 1000 machines then i don't think this is a good idea

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how)