# python script running as script using rktool faild

Tags: python-2.7, windows-services

I converted my python script into windows service using rktool. I was able to run the service but in the back ground the script was not running.

I tried different approach which is to use the skeleton provided in this link:

[Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how)

to run a simple service but again I faced issues with importing the win32 modules.

can you please help as I spent already a lot of time trying and trying and trying.

Regards,

Comment: Service hasn't too much special condition for execution, but have: a) special owner/limited rights, script can have barrier of rights (I think most scripts have problem here), b) no interaction with GUI

Comment: and give exact copy of exception / error You have