# Python27(win): import daemon, but there is an error: No module named pwd

Tags: python, daemon, pwd

1) **pip install daemon.**

[image]

2) **Open windows cmd and input: python, then input： import daemon
the terminal show**

```
>>> import daemon
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\daemon\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from .daemon import DaemonContext
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\daemon\daemon.py", line 25, in <module>
    import pwd
ImportError: No module named pwd
>>>
```

3) **pip install pwd**

**what's the problem?????**

Comment: have you tried step 2 and 3 the other way round?

Comment: C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install pwd
Collecting pwd
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pwd (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pwd

Comment: looks like no module named "pwd",

Comment: Did you install it in a distribution of Python that is different to the one you are using in your project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The pwd module is a UNIX only package, it's for managing passwords.
2. The package you are trying to install is daemon, which is an un-maintained package from 2014. There is a more recent package called [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/2.1.2), which is well maintained and used for implementing daemons in UNIX systems. It also works with python3. Though again, this will not work on windows.
3. If you're writing an application yourself and want to do this on windows you need to install it as a service, not a daemon [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how) is old, but still relevant.

Comment: python-daemon also requires `pwd` apparently

Answer (score 2):

`python-daemon` (newer version) and `daemon` both require the `pwd` package, which is not available on Windows.

Your code should detect that this is not available and disable daemon mode on Windows (which isn't really a thing).

```
try:
    import daemon
except ImportError:
    daemon = None
```

Then later, you can check if `daemon is None`.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me in `getpass` module, it worked the first time in `getpass.getuser()` but then it stopped working saying

> module pwd not found

I fixed it by repairing the python installation from the installer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Internally they are using pwd for fetching owner's name which you can avoid by simply commenting import pwd in pebblo.py[check the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHPx8.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).