# Problems with converting a Python script into a Windows service

Tags: python, windows-services

I already have a python script that runs continuously. It's very similar to this: https://github.com/walchko/Black-Hat-Python/blob/master/BHP-Code/Chapter10/file_monitor.py

Similar as in, when running it as a script, it opens a CMD which shows some data when stuff happens - it's not user-interactible so it's not mandatory that it shows (just in case someone wishes to point out that windows services can't have interfaces)

I've tried to convert it to a service. It starts for a fraction of a second and then automatically stops. When trying to start it via services.msc (instead of python script.py start) it doesn't start at all, Windows error says something like: "The service on local computer started and then stopped" which sounds just about what's happening if I try to start it with the argument.

I've tried modifying the script to allow it to run as a service - adding the skeleton I found here: [Is it possible to run a Python script as a service in Windows? If possible, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/is-it-possible-to-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows-if-possible-how)

I've also tried just getting the skeleton script above and just trying to make it run the other script with examples from here: [What is the best way to call a Python script from another Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script)

Does anyone have any idea what the best course of action would be to run that script above as a service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edited***

> *"...services can be automatically started when the computer boots, can be
>   paused and restarted, and do not show any user interface."*  ~[***Introduction to Windows Service Applications***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications)

**Windows services require the implementation to make a specific interface available:**

- [**Service Programs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685967(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [**Services**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141(v=vs.85).aspx)

**So you will need to access the Windows API through Python:**

You can see the [**example code**](http://examples.oreilly.com/9781565926219/ppw32_samples.zip), from [**Python Programming On Win32**](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/), within which Chapter 18 Services (ch18_services folder) contains a sample (SmallestService.py) demonstrating the smallest possible service written in Python:

```
# SmallestService.py
# 
# A sample demonstrating the smallest possible service written in Python.

import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event

class SmallestPythonService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "SmallestPythonService"
    _svc_display_name_ = "The smallest possible Python Service"
    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        # Create an event which we will use to wait on.
        # The "service stop" request will set this event.
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)

    def SvcStop(self):
        # Before we do anything, tell the SCM we are starting the stop process.
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        # And set my event.
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        # We do nothing other than wait to be stopped!
        win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, win32event.INFINITE)

if __name__=='__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(SmallestPythonService)
```

---

You may need to download the appropriate **pywin32** wheel for your particular python environment here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32

And [install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/) it (system wide, from admin cmd prompt):

```
> cd \program files\python<ver>\scripts
> pip install \path\to\pywin32‑221‑cp<ver>‑cp<ver>m‑win_<arch>.whl
```

Or install it (per user, from regular cmd prompt):

```
> cd \program files\python<ver>\scripts
> pip install --user \path\to\pywin32‑221‑cp<ver>‑cp<ver>m‑win_<arch>.whl
```

*Be sure to replace the occurences of `<ver>` and `<arch>` appropriately.*

Comment: Thanks for the info! And if I'd want to have the service run my other script, where and how should my code go and look like? Should I just put something like subprocess.call("script.py") under the  win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(SmallestPythonService) ?

Comment: Try starting your script from inside the SvcDoRun() function.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it sort-of worked. The service is installing and the script starts running in the same CMD I used the "python script.py install" command on. But it's not started, and it's only working as long as I leave that CMD window open. I'm getting this: "The instance's SvcRun() method failed 
<Error getting traceback - traceback.print_exception() failed 
%2: %3" in Windows Event Viewer

Comment: You need to also adjust the code inside of `__init__` and `SvcStop()` appropriately;  Remember that this is _minimal_ so you may need to add additional functions or more code inside of the existing functions.