# How to put a Python script in the background without pythonw.exe?

Tags: python, windows, background-process

I'm fairly new to Python and I have a python script that I would like to ultimately convert to a Windows executable (which I already know how to do). Is there a way I can write something **in the script** that would make it run as a background process in Windows instead of being visible in the foreground?

Comment: You are asking two different questions here. One is how to make the Python script run in the background, and the other is how to convert it to a WIndows executable. Can you please clarify if you need one or the other (they are completely independent).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Sure, just edited it.

Comment: Read about packaging Python programs into single executables (e.g. pyinstaller, cx_freeze). You can also [write a Windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32440/223424).

Comment: Are you asking how to create a Windows service, or how to simply run it in the background? A _"background process in Windows"_ is usually a service, but you can run any script in an infinite loop via the task manager or scheduler and it will happily run in the background. So please can you clarify what you are really looking for?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I would like to make the python script run as usual but without the user being able to see it

Comment: `Windows executable` all can run if supported, point is `how to run windows app with minimal additional resources ?`. Directly run need a lot library and never will be safe.

Answer (score 1):

You can always run a Windows program in the background using

```
START /B program
```

See [this post](https://superuser.com/a/591084/350717) for more information.

Comment: And you can even use `os.system("START /B "+sys.argv[0]+" --backgrounded")` if this flag not exists else drop that flag.

Comment: stdin will still be the console input buffer, which may be a problem. Use `start "title" /b [command line] < NUL` to redirect stdin to the NUL device. Unlike Unix, however, if the program tries to read from stdin, it will not be suspended. There's no shell job that allows bringing the process back to the foreground.

Comment: Also, remaining attached to the console means the application will unavoidably be killed when the console window is closed. Due to the way Python handles signals, it can't even be notified via the C runtime's `SIGBREAK` signal (to clean up and exit gracefully, etc). It would have to set a low-level console control handler via ctypes or PyWin32.

Comment: Adding to above, You can run the same in powershell.
`Start-Process python -ArgumentList "python-script-file-path" -NoNewWindow`. `Start-Process` is alias to `start`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the file using `pythonw` instead of `python` means run the command `pythonw myscript.py` instead of `python myscript.py`