# How to obtain python errors when the script is running as a service

Tags: python, windows, service

I'm writing a Windows service in Python, using win32service, as described in the top answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404). It works.

However, as I write the code, anytime I make a mistake (say, a typo in a variable name), the only feedback I get is that the service dies.

Where can I see the regular python errors?

**Edit**: I should have stated that adding a TimedRotatingFileHandler is pretty much the only thing I've added so far - and yes, it works, but it's useless to catch typos or when forgetting to prefix variables names with "self.". I still have to experiment with catching the exceptions but even if I get that to work, in my mind, it's still a workaround, not a true solution.

Comment: You could log them couldn't you? Try wrapping it in a try, and in the finally, log the exception.

Comment: A good starting point for logging: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code uses pywin32. As such, in addition to the standard

```
python myservice.py install
python myservice.py start
```

there's also an

```
python myservice.py debug
```

It won't provide all errors either, but will provide valuable clues in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest writing the program first, test it out, and then make it into a service.  Otherwise you can try trapping errors and output that to a log file.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to develop your service using an IDE like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download), that way, it can find a lost of awkwardness (like typo) for you.

It is also really important to add a logging system, and log to a file. Your service is usually executed with a specific user with different privileges, so you must pay attention to the file access rights.

You can use [AppDir](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs) Library to calculate the user log directory (see `user_log_dir` property.

Then, you can create a rotating log with a [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler).

In short:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("Rotating Log")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# add a rotating handler
handler = RotatingFileHandler(path, maxBytes=1024**3,  # 1 Mo
                              backupCount=5)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Of course, this logger must be defined in your "main" function.

Your "main" function must have an exception handler.
You need to catch all the [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) (except KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit) and log them.

To summarize:

```
def main():
    logger = init_logger()
    try:
        main_impl()
    except Exception as exc:
        logger.error("Last chance exception", exc_info=True)
        raise SystemExit(1)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but accepted as the best answer for "exc_info=True", that fulfills 80% of my needs. Thanks.