# How to write windows service to schedule run python script in particular time

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-services

I want to run a python script at a particular time. say `Everyday 10am or every 2 hours`. How can I achieve that? I have read these questions-
[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows) [Q2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29805_01/server.230/es_admin/src/radm_service_sc_syntax.html)

Comment: So what's unclear after reading these links?

Comment: Setting timer and scheduling time MR @timgeb . I'm a python beginner. Please guide me.

Comment: Why do you need a service for that? Can't you use [schtasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a service to schedule a Python script. Just use Windows Task Scheduler to run it. When I do this I usually wrap the invocation of Python in a batch file, so the scheduler runs `mytask.cmd` but you can also schedule a complete command line invocation of the interpreter, for example: `c:\python36\python.exe mytask.py`.

Task Scheduler is in the Control Panel. Open Control Panel, and in the top right hand corner ("Search Control Panel") type *Schedule*. One of the options you will get is Administrative Tools | Schedule tasks.

Comment: Any example or link to make it more clear, @BoarGules

Comment: I've added instructions for finding it in the Control Panel.

Comment: That's okay can we do this scheduling through batch script? Basically i don't want to deal with GUI. If i run a simple batch script will it able to schedule task? any idea ? @BoarGules

Comment: To do it from the command line use `schtasks.exe`. Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, @BoarGules. I will check this.