# Create the service for the email tracking in microsoft Graph using Python

Tags: python, service, microsoft-graph-api

How to create the Service (like, local machine services) for the mail(outlook) tracking using Python. Email Tracking which means that I already add some configurations into the  service. (like,I already give one of the subject name of the mail to the service).then it automatically running the service. When the same subject name of the mail comes, after that I want to read all those contents of the mail of same subject name and forward it to the another person. These all service Functionalities are done with the help of Microsoft Graph and python.Help me to How to do it!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to use EWS instead of the Graph API, give [exchangelib](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib) a try. Something like:

```
from time import sleep
from exchangelib import Account, Credentials

a = Account(
    'john@example.com', 
    credentials=Credentials('user', 'pass'), 
    autodiscover=True
)
while True:
    for m in a.inbox.filter(subject__contains='My Trigger', is_read=False):
        m.forward(
            subject='Fwd: My Trigger', 
            body='Hey, look at this!', 
            to_recipients=['carl@example.com']
        )
        m.is_read = True
        m.save(update_fields=['is_read'])
    sleep(60)
```

Comment: Is this code automatically creates Service After running the code?

Comment: What do you mean by "service"? What do you want the service to do? I hardcoded the trigger and config values to simplify the example but you could pass them via the command-line if you want (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Service means its like a System service.Press Window Button -> type SERVICE -> Press Enter. After that you will see so many services which runs in background. It automatically running when the system on. My aim is to also create a service for automatic email tracking. That's why i'm asking

Comment: Running a Python script as a Windows service is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows

Comment: exchangelib.errors.AutoDiscoverFailed: All steps in the autodiscover protocol failed