# How to "compile" a python script to an "exe" file in a way it would be run as background process?

Tags: python, compilation

I know how to run a python script as a background process, but is there any way to compile a python script into **exe** file using ***pyinstaller*** or other tools so it could have no console or window ?

Comment: what do you mean with 'no console'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run a Python script as a service in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows)

Comment: i mean when you click on my program, i dont want any prompt or window or anything to be shown, just the process be activated on background and do its job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run an executable generated with Pyinstaller without a console window, use the `--noconsole` flag (`pyinstaller --noconsole my_file.py`).

> Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o. On Mac OS X this also triggers building an OS X .app bundle. This option is ignored in *NIX systems.

See the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it in background without "console and "window" you have to run it as a service.