# Getting Error when starting a python script as a service in windows 7

Tags: python, windows, service

I want to run python script as a service. I converted My python script to .exe application using **pyinstaller** and added that application to the service using `sc create "service_name" binPath= "path of the script"` but when i am trying to start that service using **services.msc** then I am getting an error

> > Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

**Python Code:**

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("host", "user", "pass", "database")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("Insert into table(ID,date) Values({},now())".format(10))

db.commit()

cursor.close()

db.close()
```

can anyone tell me why i am getting this error and how to solve it ?

**Note:I am using Windows 7**

Comment: You get the error because you have no service control code in your program.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: ok thanks.I have run this script in linux(centos 6) as a service and i was not having any problem. @cdarke

Comment: Services (daemons) on Linux are very easy compared to services on Windows.  On Windows the Service Control Manager communicates to service threads (using a named pipe) and the service has to respond within a certain time (which you can influence).  Certainly a lot more work than on Linux.

Comment: I tried that link but getting the same error Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion @cdarke

Comment: If you look for "python how to write a windows service" in your search engine you will find lots about this.  Personally I always write my Windows services in C.

Comment: ok thanks let try something else @cdarke

Comment: This book https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/python/Python%20Programming%20on%20Win32_%20Help%20for%20Windows%20Programmers%20%5BHammond%20%26%20Robinson%202000-02-03%5D.pdf has an entire chapter on writing Windows services. Just make a bit of allowance for the fact that it was written for Python 2. I take the book down off my shelf every time I need to write a service.

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules