# SC create binpath error

Tags: windows, service

I am trying to run the following command in the PowerShell

```
sc create StrongSwan binpath= "C:\Users\Kanishk\Desktop\Strong\Strong\stronswan\strongswan-5.6.3\src\charon-svc\charon-svc.exe"
```

I have checked the path to the .exe is correct and I can cd to it also.
For reference I am following this: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Charon-svc

I am receiving the following error:

```
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'binpath='.
At line:1 char:1
+ sc create NewService binpath= C:\Users\Kanishk\Desktop\Strong\Strong\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

So my problem is the same command is working on cmd but not on PowerShell. Any reasons why?

Comment: The *URL* you provided uses `binPath=` (capital **P**). If that doesn't work try removing the space after **=**.

Comment: In the official documentation its given to have a space before any value and I have tried with binPath (capital P) also.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-create

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I ran into this also. It looks like the error happens at line:1 char:1. So I assumed it doesn't understand what "sc" is. So I changed `sc create ..` to `sc.exe create ..` and it worked for my service.

Comment: This .exe thing was required when using Powershell, but with cmd it worked.

Comment: sc.exe create   worked for me, additinonally I had to open powershell "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this with Powershell as well.

To expand on the answer:

"sc" is an alias in Powershell for "Set-Content" which is confirmed in your output and by the Powershell "Get-Alias" command. That's why sc fails but sc.exe is successful, and why sc works in cmd and fails in powershell.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying with powershell for a while but it didn't work. I thought maybe try it on Command Prompt (as an admin).
`[SC] CreateService SUCCESS`

Answer (score 1):

Use Powershell -> Run As Administrator

sc.exe create TestService binPath= "D:\Windows Services\TestService\TestService.exe"

may have to put path under "" if it contains spaces in between

Comment: sc.exe - that's exactly what I needed. Bypassed the "sc" alias.

Answer (score 1):

`SC` in **PowerShell** is an alias for the `Set-Content` command which is unrelated to **Windows services** management, and won't trigger the ***Service Control*** executable `sc.exe`.

To create a new Windows service in PowerShell you can use the `New-Service` command (requires **Administrator** privileges => "*Run as administrator*"):

```
> New-Service MyService "C:/the/path/to/myservice.exe"
Status   Name      DisplayName
------   ----      -----------
Stopped  MyService MyService
```