# How to run flask framework scripts build in python 3.6.4 as a windows service

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying for a python script written in Flask framework to implement and run as a windows service.

Have tried using different solutions like as below link:
    http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/windows_services_in_python

But getting same windows error:

```
D:\>python PySvc.py start
Starting service PySvc
Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control 
request in a timely fashion.
```

Kindly assist me, as i am not able to proceed on this.

Comment: Did u try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows

Comment: @yogi, Yes, I did tried, Service name is visible in task manager, but after starting it, i am getting the same exception as: `Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control 
request in a timely fashion.
`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your requirements are, I think you should have a look at [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/), it is a great tool to run python scripts as a service on Windows.

You can set up NSSM like this:

```
nssm.exe install MyPythonScriptService
```

Then, a dialogbox will pop up:
[Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlInb.png)

There are 3 fields that you need to fill in:

```
Application Path: C:\Python32\python.exe
Startup Directory: C:\Path\To\My\Python\Script\
Arguments: C:\Path\To\My\Python\Script\script.py
```

And then, hit Install service. Go to services.msc and make sure your service is up and running.

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows) as well
And this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96OtET8HmA0)

Hope It helps you!