# Package for creating Windows service

Tags: python

What currently can be used to distribute application as Windows service?

`py2exe` supports Python under 3.4 but `pywin32` is deprecated.
`Pyinstaller` creates `*.exe` without errors, but it works only in debug mode.

Didn't try `cx_Freeze`. As I understand it overrides service `name` that I store in my app from parsed `config.ini`?

And for `Pyinstaller` I checked all `hidden imports`.  Only `win32timezone` is needed. 
And that part was used too

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        if len(sys.argv) == 1:
            servicemanager.Initialize()
            servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(WinService)
            servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
        else:
            win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(WinService)
```

I'd like to use Python 3.x, because of unicode.

Answer (score 0):

pywin32 on sourceforge is retired. See the migration to github [pywin32-@github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32).

For an example see [python-script-as-a-service-in-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows)