# Best practice for running python consumers of a message queue?

Tags: python, windows, rabbitmq, celery, pika

I am working on a local windows web application.

I am running a RabbitMQ service and I have a python script that needs to run on the background, and consume messages from the queue (for example, using pika's `basic_consume()` function).

The question is - how should the program run on the backgroud. Some options:

1. using pythonw.exe
2. running the script as a service
3. running an IIS site

I need the code to rerun if it fails and have a simple control of stoping and restarting it.
What's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

The safe bet is number 2. Run your python code as a proper Windows service.

Take a look at this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows); using [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/).