# Python script within a Pipenv as a windows service with NSSM

Tags: python, pipenv, nssm

Using [How do you run a Python script as a service in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows) I can get a python script to run as a service. Tested it with the following code I made:

```
import os
from time import sleep
from random import *
# import flask    <-- This line breaks it only when run from NSSM

count = 0
while True:
    num = randint(1, 10000)
    count+=1
    os.mkdir("C:\\temp\\" + str(count) + '_' + str(num))
    sleep(2)
```

I tested the executable and arguments to put into NSSM by first running the following:

1. cd C:\pipenvfolder\foo
2. C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pipenv.exe
   **run python main.py**

And it starts the script successfully, even if it has imports to packages installed in the pipenv (e.g. **flask**). I then created a NSSM service with:

1. nssm.exe install ServiceName "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pipenv.exe"
   "run python main.py"
2. nssm set ServiceName AppDirectory
   "C:\pipenvfolder\foo"

And every 2 seconds it creates a directory in c:\temp. All is good. However now I wish to import one of the installed Pipenv packages, i.e. the **flask** package installed within the pipenv. So I added "import flask" to the test script above.

I then set up NSSM to have an error log and checked why it was failing to start, and it is failing to import the **flask** module:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

The **nssm** service must be starting in the correct app directory or else it would not find `main.py`. Calling it from the correct directory is what specifies the pipenv. Hence I cannot figure out why the pipenv is not being used to run the script in the same way as when run via the command line.

Answer (score 3):

Create a batch file which calls your virtual environment.
Get the virtualenv path:

```
pipenv --venv
```

service.bat

```
call path/to/.virtualenv/Scripts/activate.bat
call python main.py
```

Install the service with nssm which calls this batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt this is going to get any answers, but if someone else has the same issue.
I got around the issueby making an exe using pyinstaller. It is fairly quick and easy to do. Then I passed the .exe into NSSM as the executable to be run.

Comment: same problem... But your solution is not ideal