# How to run a node and a python script as daemon at the same time

Tags: javascript, python, executable, daemon

I just made a simple script which uses some python and some javascript. The python one grabs the most common color of the screen every 50ms and saves it to a txt, and the javascript one takes it and uses some script i found in github to change the rgb color of the motherboard with aurasync.

It works as expected, but to make it work I need 2 consoles to be open, one for each script, i wanted to know if there is a way to run both scripts as daemons or as an executable, so I dont have a terminal open in order to run it.

The node script must run as admin to work, and the python script run in a virtual environment, so I also need both things to work, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Could you specify what OS you are using? MacOS, Linux, Windows or something else?

Comment: Im using windows 10

Comment: Oh. Sorry I only know how to do it on Linux :S

Comment: So what you suggest? in case it could help

Comment: Have you considered a Windows service? Something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows) or a quick search might provide additional options.

Comment: How about startup/autostart folder? You can find it with run.exe, type "shell:startup". It will launch programs/links inside folder on login.