# Python Script Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

This is my first time to schedule a python script.
My goal is to schedule my python script to run every 10 min.

**MAIN.PY**

```
from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl news".split())
```

I created a task in windows task scheduler, but my script is not running somehow( I know the script is working since i can run it manually ). I been trying to solve this issue for hours without any luck.

First I select my python path, then I select the filepath for the project and choose the .py I want to run.
[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1b72.png)
Then I choose to trigger every 10 min.

After doing the steps described above, nothing happens. 
Hope you can help me with a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure that it will fit in your case, but I think it might. Please, check out this topic.

[How do you run a Python script as a service in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows)

Maybe you can run your script as a service and add a simple timer inside the script that launches your routine every 10 minutes from the inside.

Alternative solution that a colleague of mine is using is packing the python script inside an executable by using [fbs](https://build-system.fman.io/) or pyinstaller and adding it into the task scheduler.

Comment: I will check alternative solution after, but first I want to figure out how to deal with Windows Task Scheduler and .py

I been searching online and most guides show the same and thats why I cant understand why it is not running my script.

Comment: I will give your alternative a try. Looking at pyinstaller now.

Answer (score 0):

it might be the environment problem.The windows task scheduler is running in `C:\Windows\System32` by default,so if your some argument is not absolute path or will changed with the environment,it will get wrong result.i suggest u use some logging way to record your program's running status and result so u can debug where went wrong

Comment: Yes, but C:\Windows\System32\Tasks is a Task storage. Each Task will have its individual location added in Actions: New: Program/Script