# How to create windows service using Python

Tags: python, windows-services, pywin32

I have written a python script which will be installed in as windows service. Below is the code:

```
import datetime
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import os
import time
from random import randint
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket


def setup_logger(logger_name, log_file, level=logging.ERROR):
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    my_handler = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=100 * 1024 * 1024, backupCount=5)
    my_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    my_handler.setLevel(level)
    l = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    l.handlers[:] = []
    l.addHandler(my_handler)


curr_path = os.getcwd()
log_file = "F:\\Projects\\TestService\\logs\\application.log"
setup_logger('debug', log_file)
log = logging.getLogger('debug')

class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "test_service"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Test Service"

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)
        self.isrunning = False

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.isrunning = False

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))
        self.isrunning = True
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        while self.isrunning:
            log.error("Running {}".format(randint(00, 99)))
            time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

I have run the command `python test_service.py install` to install the service and got the correct output `Installing service test_service Service installed`. When I open services tab I can see my service listed there. When I click on start service I am getting below error:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong in the code due to which its not starting the service. Please help. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I ran the service in debug mode in `cmd` and looks like it is working fine. But from the services tab, its not working and showing above error.

```
> python test_service.py debug
      Debugging service test_service - press Ctrl+C to stop.
      Info 0x40001002 - The test_service service has started.
```

When starting the service, it gives same error:

```
> python test_service.py start
     Starting service test_service
     Error starting service: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Not sure why its not running and in debug mode it runs fine. Please help.

Comment: Hi, have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows)?

Comment: @CarloZanocco Yes have seen that and wrote all my code using that answer only. But anyways I have found the solution

Comment: Hi , Can you please share the solution, I am also facing similar problem?

Comment: @SriPallavi I have answered it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone facing this issue, just copy `pywintypes36.dll`

from `Python36\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32`

to `Python36\Lib\site-packages\win32`

Helpful commands:

1. Install a service: `python app.py install`
2. Uninstall a service: `python app.py remove`
3. Start a service: `python app.py start`
4. Update service: `python app.py update`