# How to create service for django app with nssm on windows

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nssm

### nssm service to run django application.

I have created [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) service to run my django app on windows machine but it doesn't work. Please suggest an alternative package or the right config to get the service running. Here is the command I used.

#### Adding nssm to environment variable

*some_shell>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\app\nssm" /M*

#### Creating nssm service

*some_shell>nssm install myappservice*

Here I gave *C:\Users\django_app\manage.py* as path and;

*C:\Users\django_app as Startup directory*

I get  "windows could not start the myappservice on local computer..." error whenever I try to start the service.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with nssm, but this answer might prove helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32404/how-do-you-run-a-python-script-as-a-service-in-windows/46450007#46450007

Comment: @schillingt I followed similar example but i think there's a tweak specific to django environment.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and select `python.exe` in your `env` or `venv` path
and give it "manage.py runserver" as command and set the startup path to your project
this way it gets started